# Android service pause

Tags: android, service

I have android `service` that works in the background.There is any way to pause this service while user is uses the application? (`service` must running again when user is quit from app)

Comment: use binded services.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: You need to define "pause".  A service isn't a thread.  It isn't constantly doing work-  unless you created a thread to do so.  You could set things up so that it knows when activities are paused or resumed, but "pausing" it will require you to code that, since and concept of "running" relates directly to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a `Binder` in your service, provide methods to *start and stop background work* externally, then return this `Binder` instance in `onBind()`, use `bindService` to start the service in activities, and call the `stop` method of the binder when the user opens the application. Call `start` method on exit.